# Dynamic line chart using Achartengine is not working

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

I am making dynamic line chart using Achartengine and this is working on static data but not working on dynamic data.Actual,plan and month is dynamic.I want to create line chart based on the values of actual,plan and month.I am using below code.

```
        private void drawChart() {

        XYSeries actualSeries = new XYSeries("Actual");
        // Creating an  XYSeries for Expense<br />
        XYSeries planSeries = new XYSeries("Plan");
        // Adding data to Income and Expense Series
        for (int i = 0; i <actualList.size; i++) {
            actualSeries.add(i,Double.parseDouble(actualList.get(i)));
            planSeries.add(i,Double.parseDouble(planList.get(i)));

        }
        // Creating a dataset to hold each series
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset xyMultipleSeriesDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        // Adding Income Series to the dataset
        xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(actualSeries);
        // Adding Expense Series to dataset
        xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(planSeries);

        XYSeriesRenderer actualRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        actualRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        actualRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        actualRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        actualRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        actualRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
        XYSeriesRenderer planRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        planRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        planRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        planRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        planRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        planRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
        multiRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.RED);
        multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
       /* multiRenderer.setYLabels(5);
        multiRenderer.setXLabels(1);
       */ multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
        //*  multiRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
        //multiRenderer.setShowGridY(true)
        multiRenderer.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Plan vs Actual Curve");
        multiRenderer.setXTitle("Months");
        multiRenderer.setYTitle("plan/actual");
        multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < monthList.size(); i++) {
            multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i + 1, monthList.get(i).toString());
        }

        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(actualRenderer);
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(planRenderer);

        // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout<br />
        LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout)  mView.findViewById(R.id.chart_container);
        // Creating a Line Chart<br />
        GraphicalView chart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(),   xyMultipleSeriesDataset, multiRenderer);
        chartContainer.addView(chart);
        if (chart != null) {
            chartContainer.removeView(chart);

            chart.repaint();

        }

    } 

Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I have solved my question myself after doing some research.The problem was UI update problem.Once the chart is plotted then for new data we have to remove that view and should create new chart view based on data.Below is the working code.

```
private void drawChart() {

    // Creating an  XYSeries for Income
    XYSeries actualSeries = new XYSeries("Actual");
    // Creating an  XYSeries for Expense<br />
    XYSeries planSeries = new XYSeries("Plan");
    XYSeries cupOneSeries = new XYSeries("Cup1");
    XYSeries cupTwoSeries = new XYSeries("Cup2");
    XYSeries cupThreeSeries = new XYSeries("Cup3");
    // Adding data to Income and Expense Series
    Log.e("x axis value in curve", "" + xAxisValueList.size());
    Log.e("size of Actual", actualList.size() + "");
    Log.e("size of plan", planList.size() + "");
    for (int i = 0; i < actualList.size(); i++) {
        actualSeries.add(i, Math.round(Double.parseDouble(actualList.get(i))));
        planSeries.add(i, Math.round(Double.parseDouble(planList.get(i))));
        cupOneSeries.add(i, Math.round(Double.parseDouble(cupOneList.get(i))));
        cupTwoSeries.add(i, Math.round(Double.parseDouble(cupTwoList.get(i))));
        cupThreeSeries.add(i, Math.round(Double.parseDouble(cupThreeList.get(i))));

    }
    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset xyMultipleSeriesDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    // Adding Income Series to the dataset
    xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(actualSeries);
    // Adding Expense Series to dataset
    xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(planSeries);

    xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(cupOneSeries);
    xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(cupTwoSeries);
    xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(cupThreeSeries);

    XYSeriesRenderer actualRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    actualRenderer.setColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.logo_blue));
    actualRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    actualRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    actualRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    actualRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer planRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    planRenderer.setColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.logo_orange));
    planRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    planRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    planRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    planRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    XYSeriesRenderer cupOneRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    cupOneRenderer.setColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    cupOneRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    cupOneRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    cupOneRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    cupOneRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    XYSeriesRenderer cupTwoRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    cupTwoRenderer.setColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    cupTwoRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    cupTwoRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    cupTwoRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    cupTwoRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    XYSeriesRenderer cupThreeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    cupThreeRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0D8ECF"));
    cupThreeRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    cupThreeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    cupThreeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    cupThreeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart<br />
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
    multiRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.RED);
    multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(true,false);
   /* multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sp_9));
    multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sp_9));
   */ multiRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sp_9));
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
     multiRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
    multiRenderer.setShowGridY(true);

    multiRenderer.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);
    multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Plan vs Actual Curve");
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Months");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("plan/actual");
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < monthList.size(); i++) {
        multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, monthList.get(i).toString());
    }
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(actualRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(planRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(cupOneRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(cupTwoRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(cupThreeRenderer);
    Log.e("size of actual log",actualList.size()+"");
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.chart_container);
    if (monthList.size() > 0) {
        // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout<br />

        chartContainer.removeAllViews();
        //drawing bar chart<br />
        chart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), xyMultipleSeriesDataset, multiRenderer);
        //adding the view to the linearlayout<br />
        chartContainer.addView(chart);

    } else {
        chartContainer.removeAllViews();
        CustomToast.initToast(getActivity(),"No data available for S-curve");
    }


}
```